# Save a multi-column custom sort for easy access by other users.

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, sorting

I have a large table in Excel 2013 which I will be distributing to a group of users. Each row in the table has a unique ID, with a combination of alphabetical characters, numbers, and periods. For example: DL3.4.10.2.2

I've created seven helper columns to allow the table to be properly sorted by the custom ID. So the custom sort involves 7 levels.

As users interact with this table, they will be sorting on a number of columns in the table. They will also need to return to the custom ID sort regularly. Is there a way for me save the custom sort of the helper columns to make this easier for the users?

Comment: There is no good way to save a set of sort criteria.  When I have needed to do this, I usually create some VBA which applies the desired criteria.  Fortunately, this is a macro that will record easily so you can usually just record and run when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a neat solution for your problem. The solution I think of is composed of two pieces: [Advanced filters](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b) and [Scenario's](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-between-various-sets-of-values-by-using-scenarios-2068afb1-ecdf-4956-9822-19ec479f55a2).

Using an [Advanced Filter](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b), you can filter your data based on the values of cells in your worksheet. Use that to create a set of criteria that satisfies your situation.

Next, you can use [Scenario's](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-between-various-sets-of-values-by-using-scenarios-2068afb1-ecdf-4956-9822-19ec479f55a2) to save a set of criteria that you can use (and select) as needed.